# Can Yasuo's wind wall block Gangplank's keg connection?

Tags: league-of-legends

Imagine Gangplank has more than one barrel placed and yasuo places a wind wall between them.

Can the wind wall block the detonation of the second barrel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, the connection between barrels is not considered a skill-shot or a projectile, nor it is the explosion of the barrel which is normal AOE damage.

The only way Yasou can prevent barrels' explosion is to windwall GP's Q to the first barrel of the chain.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently **Yasuo's wind wall can't block gankplank's barrel's chain reactions** for sure.
But it maybe possible to block the damage from a barrel placed in front of the wall.

so basically the powder trail is not coded as a projectel, just an effect to let you know it's gonna go boom.

Comment: It shouldn't block damage from the barrel, as that's not a projectile either.